# Struts2 convention and redirect parameters

Tags: struts2, convention

I use a Struts2 Convention plug-in to map my actions. Please, help me to solve the following problem. Here I have an action mapping

```
@Action(value="/{categorie:\\w+}/{hoofdgroep:\\w+}/{artikelgroep:\\w+}/", results = {
    @Result(name="success", location="articlelist.jsp"),
    @Result(name="maingroup", location="/%{categorie}/%{hoofdgroep}/", type="redirect"),
    @Result(name="category", location="/%{categorie}/", type="redirect")
}, interceptorRefs = {
    ...
})
public String execute() throws Exception {
   ...
   Category category = service.getCategory(categorie);
   if (category == null) return NONE;
   ...
   MainGroup mGroup = service.getMainGroup(hoofdgroep);
   if (mGroup == null) return "category";
   ...
   ArticleGroup artGroup = service.getArticleGroup(artikelgroep);
   if (artGroup == null) return "maingroup";
   ...
   return SUCCESS;
}
```

When, for instance, there is no artGroup for specified artikelgroep it should redirect `link _http://site/categorie/hoofdgroep/artikelgroep/` to url `_http://site/categorie/hoofdgroep/` which it perfectly does. The only problem here is that it also prepends additional parameters which are undesired. So link _`http://site/categorie/hoofdgroep/artikelgroep/` is redirected to `_http://site/categorie/hoofdgroep/?categorie=categorie&hoofdgroep=hoofdgroep&artikelgroep=artikelgroep.`

My question is How to get rid of these parameters?

Here are some config params from my struts.properties file

```
...
struts.serve.static=false
struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess=true
struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation=false
struts.action.extension= ,
struts.url.includeParams=none

struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames=true
struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace=false
struts.patternMatcher=regex

struts.convention.default.parent.package=app-default
struts.convention.action.packages=...
struts.convention.action.alwaysMapExecute=false
struts.convention.package.locators.disable=true
struts.convention.relative.result.types=dispatcher
struts.convention.result.path=/WEB-INF/jsp/
```

So basically is this a bug or it should work this way?

Perhaps it is not so elegant solution but here what I have done. I overrode `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult#getProhibitedResultParams`

```
public class ServletRedirectResult
        extends org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult
{

    public ServletRedirectResult() {
        super();
        initProhibitedResultParams();
    }

    public ServletRedirectResult(String location) {
        super(location);
        initProhibitedResultParams();
    }

    public ServletRedirectResult(String location, String anchor) {
        super(location, anchor);
        initProhibitedResultParams();
    }

    private List<String> prohibitedParamNames;

    private void initProhibitedResultParams() {

        String[] parentParams = (String[])super.getProhibitedResultParams().toArray();
        int len = parentParams.length;
        String[] params = new String[len + 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            params[i] = parentParams[i];
        }
        params[len] = "statusCode";

        // TODO: This is a temporary solution because RegexPatternMatcher puts parameters
        // from urls into ResultConfig for some reason.
        params[len+1] = "categorie";
        params[len+2] = "hoofdgroep";
        params[len+3] = "artikelgroep";

        prohibitedParamNames = Arrays.asList(params);
    }

    protected List<String> getProhibitedResultParams() {
        return prohibitedParamNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could pass those values into the action, compose the location string you want and reference that new string instead. Have you thought about turning this functionality into an interceptor once you have it working?

Comment: I've never seen an @Action statement like that before. Could someone explain (or point me to some documentation) what     @Action(value="/{categorie:\\w+}/{hoofdgroep:\\w+}/{artikelgroep:\\w+}/" actually means

Comment: To @user497087. You can write like so when using [wildcard regexp pattern macher](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.2/docs/wildcard-mappings.html) (struts.patternMatcher=regex) plus [Convention plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.2/docs/convention-plugin.html)

Comment: To @Quaternion. Can you clarify what do you mean? I already have values of /categorie/hoofdgroep/artikelgroep/ in the corresponding fields of an Action when I write like so [ @Action(value="/{categorie:\\w+}/{hoofdgroep:\\w+}/{artikelgroep:\\w+}/",..]. And why do I need an interceptor? I have three separate actions which handles three types of urls /categorie/hoofdgroep/artikelgroep/, /categorie/hoofdgroep/ and /categorie/ and it is enough for me.

Comment: That was not clear until now... the redirects could have been forwarding to many actions, if that was the case then an interceptor would be good.  In your case it does not matter. But knowing that you only need to handle three url patterns... I would have made three different actions and probably placed them in the same class, without any forwards. It looks like if someone gets the url wrong you want it to backtrack automatically to a higher level? I would just show an error page.

Comment: To @Quaternion. I would show an error page as well but that was customer's requirement, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is the default behaviour of both com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.NamedVariablePatternMatcher and org.apache.struts2.util.RegexPatternMatcher however it not the behaviour of com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.WildcardHelper (which is the default implementation)

From what you have shown the default implementation can handle what you are doing with far less headaches (regular wildcard matching).

Consulting this page: http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.2/docs/wildcard-mappings.html

It states for "Parameters in namespaces" (I know you are not using this):

> From Struts 2.1+ **namespace patterns can be extracted as request
>   parameters** and bound to the action.

However this equally applies to what is happening in the action and it really seems to be the only behaviour (where I would assume from "can be" that there would be another choice when it should have really been written as "... namespace/action patterns **are** extracted as request parameters...") and it seems to apply to the regex pattern matching equally, it would be nice for the documentation to more explicitly state this.

From your comments I can better understand what you are doing...

Why don't you simply set up three actions for:

```
*/*/*, */* and *
```

Then just pass the numbered parameters into the action?

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. The explanation part about "Parameters in namespaces" stays unclear to me. As long a you have said that "What you describe is the default behaviour of both  com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.NamedVariablePatternMatcher..." and to activate "Parameters in namespaces" we have to set struts.patternMatcher=namedVariable. Indeed I can manage action mapping with the */*/*, */*, * and numbered parameters but I do not know how it will work because I also have urls like '/customer/passrestore/forgetPassword' and '/customer/registerCustomer'. Would be there any conflicts?

Comment: In any case is that a correct behavior for  NamedVariablePatternMatcher and RegexPatternMatcher? If they define some parameters in action configuration wile making `@Action(value="/{categorie:\\w+}/{hoofdgroep:\\w+}/{artikelgroep:\\w+}/"...` mapping they should be declared on Action level not on the result level. E.g. they should be present in the invocation.getProxy().getConfig().getParams() but not in the ResultConfig#getParams(). But maybe I am mistaken. Anyway, I've chosen a solution by overriding `ServletRedirectResult#getProhibitedResultParams` and added those params for exclusion.

Comment: There should be no conflict between _*/*/*_ and _*/*_ ... I'm saying use the default, not the named or regex options.

Answer (score 0):

I was digging into the code of `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult#doExecute`. Probably this piece prepends undesired parameters

```
ResultConfig resultConfig = invocation.getProxy().getConfig().getResults().get(invocation.getResultCode());
if (resultConfig != null)
{
    Map<String, String> resultConfigParams = resultConfig.getParams();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : resultConfigParams.entrySet())
    {
        if (!getProhibitedResultParams().contains(e.getKey()))
        {
            String potentialValue = e.getValue() == null ? "" : conditionalParse(e.getValue(), invocation);
            if (!suppressEmptyParameters || ((potentialValue != null) && (potentialValue.length() > 0)))
            {
                    requestParameters.put(e.getKey(), potentialValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is nothing wrong with this code. And the question is Why those three parameters appeared in the ResultConfig? Because it is working like, when you write like so

```
 <result name="maingroup" type="redirect">
     <param name="location">/${categorie}/${hoofdgroep}/</param>
     <param name="namespace">/</param>
     <param name="categorie">${categorie}</param>
     <param name="hoofdgroep">${hoofdgroep}</param>
     <param name="artikelgroep">${artikelgroep}</param>
 </result>
```